# Admob Adview enable gesture

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have a Admob banned Adview which is used to show banner ad. The view is inside a relative layout.

I want to enable gesture listener on that AdView so that user can swipe the add to close it. Unfortunately adview doesnot allow me add my own custom onTouch listener.

How do i do it?

Comment: Have you tried taking adview in a container and adding touch listener to that?

Comment: By container u mean relative layout etc?

Comment: Yes some kind of view group, containing that AdView.